# How can I add helper scripts docker-php-ext-configure, docker-php-ext-install in my docker image

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I got detail about some helper scripts but I do not know how to add the support of these scripts in docker file. When I try to use the scripts

Scripts like:   docker-php-ext-configure, docker-php-ext-install, and docker-php-ext-enable to more easily install PHP extensions.

I am getting errors like:  /bin/sh: 1: docker-php-ext-configure: not found

I am using

```
FROM debian:stretch
```

for build docker container in my docker file.

Same helper scripts are working perfectly fine inn different images like:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

FROM php:7.2-apache
```

If we build Docker file with these images.

Comment: They get COPY'd into the container in the PHP official images via their Dockerfile (e.g. https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.2/stretch/apache/Dockerfile). You can find copies of the files that get copied in https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.2/stretch/apache.

Comment: Did the same but now getting error : gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address
ERROR: Service 'xxxxx-dev' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c set -xe;

Answer (score 1):

php:7.X-apache image is already pre-built with all those scripts included as can be seen here: https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.2/stretch/apache

If you need PHP 7.1 image/files you can try to search repository for last version of 7.1 image before it was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

All of those scripts can be found in this repo:

https://github.com/docker-library/php

Just RUN the scripts within your project directory via Dockerfile, or COPY over to the /usr/bin folder then RUN as you would any other bin script. Just keep in mind those scripts assume an Alpine-esque directory structure so if you're using something like Debian/Ubuntu it may not work out of the box.